# Marklogic, Deleting Scheduled task with task ID

Tags: marklogic

We are using the admin apis to create the schedule, which is working fine and getting scheduled. Similarly we would like to delete the task using admin API. But we either need the task ID or the task node to delete the task. But I looked around in the api i could not find a way to retrieve the task id. do we have an api to get the scheduled task id or we just have to use the task node to delete the task.

Answer (score 1):

You are probably looking for:  [DELETE /manage/v2/tasks/{id|name}](https://docs.marklogic.com/REST/DELETE/manage/v2/tasks/[id-or-name])

Please note that even though the description says: "This resource address deletes the **named** task from the named group.", it actually works by name or ID.

Comment: Thanks for the response, sorry forget to mention we are not using ML8, is there way to do this in earlier versions 6 or 7?

Answer (score 1):

With older versions of MarkLogic, your best bet would be [admin:group-get-scheduled-tasks()](http://docs.marklogic.com/admin:group-get-scheduled-tasks). Iterate through them till you find the one you are looking for. After that you can either take the task-id from the XML, and use that, or pass through the entire task XML for deletion.

HTH!

Comment: Yes, I am also trying that only, but can we get the task-id from there, I could delete using the task node, but i could not find task-id any where

Comment: I do get task-id as part of the task XML, but I am running ML 8.0-4. Maybe you are on an older release? In that case, just use the entire returned XML to delete the task with [admin:group-delete-scheduled-task](http://docs.marklogic.com/admin:group-delete-scheduled-task). Contrary to [admin:group-delete-scheduled-task-by-id](http://docs.marklogic.com/admin:group-delete-scheduled-task-by-id), this takes the task XML instead of the taks ID..

Comment: Yes, we are already using the task node to delete the task, but task id will be much more helpfull